# Talking about two events in the past: should the one closer to the present be in a past tense or present tense?

Tags: grammaire, participe-passé

In the book of *French Grammar and Usage*, by Hawkins & Towell on page 247-248, it is given that

> But if the more distant event does not have continuing consequences, a pluperfect form of the verb will be used in French:
>
> > Il avait arrêté de fumer depuis plus d'un an quand il **est** tombé malade
> >
> > He had stopped smoking for more than a year when he became ill

and then

> Whereas the simple past and compound past tenses refer to events completed in the past from the perspective of the speaker or writer, the pluperfect describes events completed at some point even before these past events:
>
> > La police **laissa** une balise pour indiquer où l'accident était arrivé
> >
> > The police left a marker to show where the accident happened/had happened (Pluperfect - an event which occurred prior to the police marking the spot)

However, I'm confused: when talking about two events in the past, one is in a distant past then the other, should the one closer to the present be in a past tense (as in the second example) or in the present tense (as in the first example)?

Comment: There is no verb at the present tense in the first example. *Il est tombé malade* is *passé composé*.

Comment: @jlliagre according to: https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-etre.html, `est` is present form of `etre`

Comment: That is correct but in your case, *être* is an auxiliary verb and *est tombé* is the *passé composé* of [*tomber*](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-tomber.html).

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, I see. Just out of curiosity: is it a passive construction?

Comment: It is an active one: *Il est tombé malade* = "he fell ill" / "he got sick".

Comment: @jlliagre but `est` is a `to be` verb, and `tombe` is a verb. How can they go together; it doesn't make sense

Comment: Auxiliary verbs are a fact. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb